# Data Structure ASSIGNMENT

Tags: generics, data-structures

NOTE: You can add only one function into the linked list class get_at_position which will return va

lue of element at given position.

1. Insert before tail :  Insert a value into a simply linked list, such that it's location will be before tail.

So if a list contains {1, 2, 3}, insert before tail value 9 is called, the list will become {1, 2, 9, 3}.

2. Insert before value :  Insert a value into a simply linked list, such that it's location will be before a particular value.

So if a list contains {1, 2, 3}, insert before 2 value 9 is called, the list will become {1, 9, 2, 3}.

3)Count common elements : Count common values between two simply linked lists.
So if a list1 contains {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, and list2 contains {1, 3, 4, 6}, number of common elements is 3.

4. Check if sorted : Check if elements of simply linked lists are sorted in ascending order or not.
   So if a list contains {1, 3, 7, 8, 9} its sorted, but if a list contains {1, 3, 7, 2, 5} its not sorted.
5. Find sublist  : Find and return sublist in a list, the start and stop positions indicate where the sublist starts and where it ends.
   So if a list contains {1, 3, 7, 8, 9}, sublist at start 2 and stop 4 is {3, 7, 8}

Comment: Seems like a reasonable assignment. What is the question?

Comment: The doctor publish it like this 
there is an answer in chegg and bartleby 
but these sites need money that i can't pay it for ....

Comment: I sympathize, but what is the question? This is a questions and answer site, not a "please do my homework for me" kinda site. You need to tell us what you tried, hopefully post some code, and ask a specific question.